# Access @ObservedObject object from SwiftUI class into UIKit class and update it

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, publish-subscribe, observedobject

I am trying to access the `@ObservedObject` object from `SwiftUI` class into `UIKit` class and trying to update the value as well. When I update the value from UIKit class, then it is not receiving broadcast to SwiftUI class.
Here is my code snippet:

In SwiftUI

```
public class HomeNavBar : ObservableObject{
    @Published var leftButton:Bool = false
    @Published var rightBottom:Bool = false
}


public struct HomeView : View{

@ObservedObject var model: HomeNavBar

public init(model: HomeNavBar){
   self.model = model
}

public var body: some View{
    
    ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
        
        VStack{
            if model.leftButton{
                print("add left button related code")               
          }
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
    }
    
}
```

In UIKit (swift) class

```
import SwiftUI
struct MyNavBarConfigurator {
   private var model = HomeNavBar()
   func show(){
      model.leftButton = true //this should invoke the body in HomeView class of SwiftUI
   }
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you ensure that you have the same instance of `HomeNavBar` in both objects?

Comment: AFAIK, `ObservableObject` is only for use in a SwiftUI `View`, not any class.

Comment: @Paulw11 It ensures in SwiftUI like this
public struct HomeNavVCWrapper: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    public private(set) var model = HomeNavBar()

    public func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewControllerType   {
  model.leftButton.toggle() //it invokes HomeView

 }

}
So expecting same with UIKit class as well. Any other way that we can achieve this?

Comment: Every time you call “ HomeNavBar() ” you create a different instance one does not know about the other.

Comment: You can make HomeNavBar as singleton class and update the value from UIKit class.

Comment: Or simply pass it in as a dependency. Also, your "UIKit (swift) class" is a struct.

Comment: @loremipsum and all, yes you all are right. I thought it would be possible in SwiftUI (as am a learner). I have achieved by using the Binding in MyNavBarConfigurator class.

Comment: Binding is only for SwiftUI Views not classes. You’ll run into issues.

Comment: @loremipsum I don't think so. As per my knowledge Binding will create a two way communication between any two classes. So from UIKit, I would update the Binging value which triggers the SwiftUI class to rearrange the view.

Comment: @GaneshG `Binding` can create a 2 way connection between **"value"** types `class` is reference not value. `Binding` conforms to `DynamicProperty` and because of that it needs a `body` to get updated values. You will see bugs. `Binding` does not work in UIKit either. Sometimes depending on the setup an update will piggyback on another update so it seems to work but it is unreliable. Anything that conforms to `DynamicProperty` relies on `body`